# Can HTML <script> tags connect from different points?

Tags: javascript, html

As i was making my text rpg, i was wondering if i could make my javascript in the  tags but, in a weird order, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    ex();  // Call the function here
  </script>

  <script>
    function ex() {
      alert('test'); // Make the function here
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: apart from the answer below you can put you javascript wherever you like, however in practice it generally should come just below the closing ```</body>``` tag

Comment: So, I would be able to do it like how I was asking- `</body> <script> </script>` etc.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction

Answer (score 1):

No, the variable/function has to be defined before you call it

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ex is not defined
```

**Clarification**

You can put your scripts wherever you please and the variables/functions will be shared, but they have to be in the correct order

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering that because how the scripts are in different areas, so it would connect either way.